# Why are V speeds the last to be uploaded into a FMC?

Tags: aircraft-performance, fms

When uploading performance information into an FMC, if you put the speeds in before other performance calculations you may get a warning. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the V speeds are critical to the takeoff performance for the configuration you are departing in, and the FMS won't let you enter them until all the other data is in place, like fuel weights, all up weights, temperature, altitude, etc, etc, etc. It's doing an idiot-proofing function.